# Mapping enum to value

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, mapping

I am using a Badge component

```
<Badge statusColour={value} label={value} />
```

From the API, I am getting a status which has the following enum:

```
enum Status {
  Requested = 'Requested',
  Approved = 'Approved',
  Declined = 'Declined',
}
```

The Badge component statusColour prop ONLY takes the following colour strings: "attention", "resolved", "rejected".

Each Status enum has it's corresponding statusColour

```
  Requested = 'attention',
  Approved = 'resolved',
  Declined = 'rejected',
```

Is there a way to map the Status enums to the colour strings so that when I use the Badge component like this:

```
const value = Status.Requested
<Badge statusColour={value} label={value} />
```

the value in status is: 'attention'

and value in label is: 'Requested'

p.s. I am using TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look it up by indexing the status color enum (i.e. `StatusColor[value]`).

## Complete example

```
enum Status {
  Requested = 'Requested',
  Approved = 'Approved',
  Declined = 'Declined',
}

enum StatusColor {
  Requested = 'attention',
  Approved = 'resolved',
  Declined = 'rejected',
}

const valueToColor = (value: Status): StatusColor => StatusColor[value];

console.log(valueToColor(Status.Requested)); // attention
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I am going to use a type instead of enum given this is TypeScript. Thanks